# How to pass multiple parameter in add_action()

Tags: admin, actions

I have below code.

```
add_action( 'admin_init', [$this, 'settings_page_registration'] );
```

I would like to use `enqueue_assets` function name inside `add_action()`.

Should I use like below ?

```
add_action( 'admin_init', [$this, 'settings_page_registration', 'enqueue_assets'] );
```

Comment: No, that's not how it works. What are you trying to do? Why do you need to pass the function name like that?

Comment: Thanks @JacobPeattie. I would like to call the function at `admin_init`. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to call `enqueue_assets` at `admin_init`, then add a new `add_action()`:

```
add_action( 'admin_init', [$this, 'settings_page_registration'] );
add_action( 'admin_init', [$this, 'enqueue_assets'] );
```

- https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_action/

That said, if your assets are JS scripts or CSS, you should consider `wp_enqueue_script()` & `wp_enqueue_scripts`

- https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script
- https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_enqueue_scripts/

Comment: This is the correct approach. One advantage of this method that I would like to point out is that, when each function is added separately, each function can later be removed independently by using `remove_action`, if ever needed.